# Pyspark DataFrame loop

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

I am new to Python and DataFrame. Here I am writing a Python code to run an ETL job in AWS Glue. Please find the same code snippet below.

```
test_DyF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="teststoragedb", table_name="testtestfile_csv")
test_dataframe = test_DyF.select_fields(['empid','name']).toDF()
```

now the above test_dataframe is of type `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`

Now, I need to loop through the above **test_dataframe**. As far as I see, I could see only `collect` or `toLocalIterator`. Please find the below sample code

`for row_val in test_dataframe.collect():`

But both these methods are very slow and not efficient. I cannot use pandas as it is not supported by AWS Glue.

Please find the steps I am doing

source information:

```
productid|matchval|similar product|similar product matchval
product A|100|product X|100
product A|101|product Y|101
product B|100|product X|100
product C|102|product Z|102
```

expected result:

```
product |similar products
product A|product X, product Y
product B|product X
product C|product Z
```

This is the code I am writing

1. I am getting a distinct dataframe of the source with productID
2. Loop through this distinct data frame set

   a) get the list of matchval for the product from the source

   b) identify the similar product based on matchval filters

   c) loop through to get the concatinated string  ---> This loop using the rdd.collect is affecting the performance

Can you please share any better suggestion on what can be done?

Comment: what’s the logic you are trying to implement by looping?

Comment: Hi @MohammadMurtazaHashmi , Basically I have nested loops, I face this issue in the inner for loop as the collect() will be called multiple times. I need to get the name in comma seperated format in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please elaborate what logic you want to try it out. DF looping can be done via SQL approach or you can also follow below RDD approach

```
def my_function(each_record):
#my_logic

#loop through for each command. 
df.rdd.foreach(my_function)
```

Added following code further based on your input

```
df = spark.read.csv("/mylocation/61250775.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True, sep="|")
seq = ['product X','product Y','product Z']
df2 = df.groupBy("productid").pivot("similar_product",seq).count()

+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|productid|product X|product Y|product Z|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|product B|        1|     null|     null|
|product A|        1|        1|     null|
|product C|     null|     null|        1|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The final approach which match your requirement

df = spark.read.csv("/mylocation/61250775.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True, sep="|")
    df.printSchema()

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- matchval1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- similar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- matchval3: integer (nullable = true)


from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
dfx = df.groupBy("id").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list("similar")).alias("Similar_Items")).select(col("id"), col("Similar_Items"))
dfx.show()

+---------+-------------------+
|       id|      Similar_Items|
+---------+-------------------+
|product B|          product X|
|product A|product X,product Y|
|product C|          product Z|
+---------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have added the details in the question. Can you please check?

Comment: Thank you H Roy for the detailed steps. Based on what I see, this can be achieved without the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the MAP class. In my case, I was iterating through data and calculate hash for the full row.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import hashlib

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "load-test", table_name = "table_test", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "load-test", table_name = "table_test", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

def hash_calculation(rec):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    md5.update('{}_{}_{}_{}'.format(rec["funcname"],rec["parameter"],rec["paramtype"],rec["structure"]).encode())
    rec["hash"]  = md5.hexdigest()
    print("looping the recs")
    return rec
    
mapped_dyF =  Map.apply(frame = datasource0, f = hash_calculation)
```